# JqueryUI - Dialog open multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

the problem occurs when I re-press `#btn3`. After that, when i open the dialog using `#button_create_product` dialogue window is duplicated as many times as was pressed `#btn3`. The `button_create_product` described in `products.jsp`
PS `$('#button_create_product').unbind("click")` doesn't help

```
  $('#btn3').click(function () {
            $('#menu').load("products.jsp",function () {
                $('#button_create_product').click( function() {
                    $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');

                });
                $( ".dialog_create_product" ).dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    width: 800,
                    buttons: {
                        OK: function() {
                            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")

                        },
                        CANSEL: function() {
                            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")
                        }
                    },
                });
            });
        });
```

Html

```
    <body class="products">

<button id = "button" class="remove">Удалить выделенное</button>
<button id = "button_create_product" class="button_create_product">Добавить продукт</button>

<hr>
<table id="products_table" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Категория</th>
        <th>Производитель</th>
        <th>Название</th>
        <th>Штрихкод</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th class="searchable">Каталог</th>
        <th class="searchable">Производитель</th>
        <th class="searchable">Название</th>
        <th class="searchable">Штрихкод</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="dialog_create_product" title="Создать продукт" hidden>
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="width: 70%">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select class="selectCategory" style="width: 100%">
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="prodName" placeholder="Название" type="text" style="width:  100%" maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="prodProvider" placeholder="Производитель" type="text" style="width:  100%" maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="prodCode" placeholder="штрих-код" type="text" style="width:  100%" maxlength="50"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <table class="sostav" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" style="width: 700px">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="50%" align="center"><b>Компоненты</b><hr></td>
            <td width="50%" align="center"><b>Состав</b><hr></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class = "components"  height="200px" valign="top"></td>
            <td class = "compound"  height="200px" valign="top"></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="divInput"align="center">
        <input class = "getInputComponent" placeholder="название компонента" type="text" maxlength="50"><button class="addComponent" >Добавить компонент</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: could it be that it creates products each time and that close only hides it? so that when you click the button again it shows all of them and adds one?

Comment: are there multiple items with the class .dialog_create_product? this line  $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');
will open all elements with this class. Displaying the HTML code behind this jQuery code would be helpful

Comment: Alex, when ok  pressed  all windows was closed and created just one product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you click on `#btn`, another `click` handler to `#button_create_product`. As a result, when you click on `#button_create_product`, that handler runs multiple times.

Take the `$('#button_create_product').click` code out of the callback function, and just do it once when the page is loaded. Use a variable to track whether the button has been clicked.

```
var button_clicked = false;
$('#button_create_product').click( function() {
    if (button_clicked) {
        $('.dialog_create_product').dialog('open');
    }
});
$( ".dialog_create_product" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 800,
    buttons: {
        OK: function() {
            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")

        },
        CANSEL: function() {
            $(".dialog_create_product").dialog("close")
        }
    },
});
$("#btn3").click(function() {
    $('#menu').load("products.jsp",function () {
        button_clicked = true;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. this will stop your extra event firing.

```
$(".btn3").click(function(event) {
  event.stopImmediatePropagation();
  //Do Stuff
});
```